# ESLint: Demanding a semicolon but also wants it removed

Tags: typescript, eslint

Every time I run my lint script trough my code, it throws an error about a missing semicolon. However, after I put on the missing semicolons, I run ESLint again and it throws an error about an extra semicolon on the exact same lines and file.

My code looks like this:

```
import { atom } from 'recoil';
import { OrderItemType } from '../types/OrderItemType';

export const orderItemsAtom = atom<OrderItemType[]>({
  key: 'values',
  default: []
});
```

My `.eslint.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard-with-typescript"
    ],
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "no-prototype-builtins": "off",
        "react/jsx-handler-names": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "import/no-cycle": "off",
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "off",
        "no-param-reassign": "off",
        "react/no-array-index-key": "off",
        "no-nested-ternary": "off",
        "react/require-default-props": "off",
        "no-plusplus": "off",
        "no-useless-return": "off",
        "no-useless-escape": "off",
        "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
        "class-methods-use-this": "off",
        "react/jsx-no-useless-fragment": "off"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    }
}
```

The missing/extra semicolon error is thrown on both imports and the export.

Comment: You can hover on lint error and see the rule name, and you can find out which two are conflicting.

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat The error doesn't get inlined in the code, it only gets thrown on the console

Comment: It should also say which rule is detecting the error in the console. Can you paste the console output here?